# Is there a way for me to calculate an average similarity of strings, grouped by individuals?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Some context: I'm currently working on data on Fraud Detection and my data looks like the following with relevant columns:

| referee | referee_phone_number | referred_by |
| --- | --- | --- |
| referee_A | 019500600 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_B | 019500601 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_C | 019500602 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_D | 019500603 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_E | 014501928 | Person B_non_fraudster |
| referee_F | 016779810 | Person B_non_fraudster |

Notice that the phone numbers referred by Person A are similar. Fraudsters tend to register phone numbers en masse.

One feature that I would like to engineer would be string similarity grouped by `referred_by`, which looks something like this, with approximates for the average value similarities to be fed into my decision tree, with the goal of using the value for training, since non-frausters will low phone number similarities:

| referred_by | average_phone_number_similarity |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | 0.90 |
| Person B | 0.20 |

I've tried exploring `Levenstein Distance` and have the following script using `difflib` , thinking that I could pit two lists together:

```
string_list_1 = ['02223785428', '02223785390', '02223784947', '0165104490']
string_list_2 = ['02223785428', '02223785390', '02223784947']

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

similar = []
not_similar = []
for item1 in string_list_1:

    # Set the state as false
    found = False
    for item2 in string_list_2:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, a=item1,b=item2).ratio() > 0.8:
            similar.append(item1)
            found = True
            break
    
    if not found:
        not_similar.append(item1)

# Making sure that there is not duplcates in the list
print("Similar : ", list(dict.fromkeys(similar)))
print("Not Similar : ", list(dict.fromkeys(not_similar)))

>> Similar :  ['02223785428', '02223785390', '02223784947']
Not Similar :  ['0165104490']
```

However, it doesn't solve my issue, especially when it comes to computing similarity between each phone number, I don't think I am getting it quite right, can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Look into sequence to sequence neural machinery, also.  the decoder predicts what number will come next.   If the decoder generates output the input phone number could be fraud.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly.
But why don't you want to compare the difference between two integers? If you expect numbers in a row, then you can just store integers in the database and trying to find some close numbers for a period.

Comment: I know the solution to this is somewhere along the lines of comparing the differences between two strings, or in this case, integers, depending on what type of data types that you'd want to work with, but in this case, when presented with the original dataframe, I am still thinking about a proper implementation. Because i'd only want to compare the differences in phone numbers along the same referrer in this case.